# /var/lib/mailman/cgi-bin bad group (has: root, expected list) (fixing)

Tags: permissions, postfix, mail, symbolic-link, dovecot

I'm just trying to install mailman so that the permissions are correct, but no matter what I do mailman installs with the wrong permissions:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ sudo apt-get install mailman
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  spamassassin lynx listadmin
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mailman
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/10.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 35.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 233409 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking mailman (from .../mailman_1%3a2.1.16~rc2-1_i386.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Setting up libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 (1.5.2-1) ...
Setting up libaprutil1-ldap (1.5.2-1) ...
Setting up apache2-bin (2.4.6-2ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up apache2-data (2.4.6-2ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up apache2 (2.4.6-2ubuntu2.1) ...
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                                   [ OK ] 
Setting up mailman (1:2.1.16~rc2-1) ...
Looking for enabled languages (this may take some time) ... done.
Installing site language en ............................................ done.
Configuring mailman for domain dur.bounceme.net ...
Upgrading from version 0x0 to 0x20110c2
getting rid of old source files
update-rc.d: warning: default stop runlevel arguments (0 1 6) do not match mailman Default-Stop values (none)
 * Site list for mailman missing (looking for list named 'mailman').
 * Please create it; until then, mailman will refuse to start.
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ sudo newlist mailman
Enter the email of the person running the list: thufir@dur.bounceme.net
Initial mailman password: 
To finish creating your mailing list, you must edit your /etc/aliases (or
equivalent) file by adding the following lines, and possibly running the
`newaliases' program:

## mailman mailing list
mailman:              "|/var/lib/mailman/mail/mailman post mailman"
mailman-admin:        "|/var/lib/mailman/mail/mailman admin mailman"
mailman-bounces:      "|/var/lib/mailman/mail/mailman bounces mailman"
mailman-confirm:      "|/var/lib/mailman/mail/mailman confirm mailman"
mailman-join:         "|/var/lib/mailman/mail/mailman join mailman"
mailman-leave:        "|/var/lib/mailman/mail/mailman leave mailman"
mailman-owner:        "|/var/lib/mailman/mail/mailman owner mailman"
mailman-request:      "|/var/lib/mailman/mail/mailman request mailman"
mailman-subscribe:    "|/var/lib/mailman/mail/mailman subscribe mailman"
mailman-unsubscribe:  "|/var/lib/mailman/mail/mailman unsubscribe mailman"

Hit enter to notify mailman owner...

thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ ll /var/lib/mailman/
total 36
drwxrwsr-x  8 root list 4096 Jan  5 09:00 ./
drwxr-xr-x 71 root root 4096 Jan  5 09:00 ../
drwxrwsr-x  4 root list 4096 Jan  5 09:00 archives/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   20 Aug 21 02:16 bin -> /usr/lib/mailman/bin/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   24 Aug 21 02:16 cgi-bin -> /usr/lib/cgi-bin/mailman/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   21 Aug 21 02:16 cron -> /usr/lib/mailman/cron/
drwxrwsr-x  2 root list 4096 Jan  5 09:00 data/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   25 Aug 21 02:16 icons -> /usr/share/images/mailman/
drwxrwsr-x  3 root list 4096 Jan  5 09:01 lists/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   17 Aug 21 02:16 locks -> /var/lock/mailman/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   16 Aug 21 02:16 logs -> /var/log/mailman/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   21 Aug 21 02:16 mail -> /usr/lib/mailman/mail/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   24 Aug 21 02:16 Mailman -> /usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/
drwxr-xr-x 40 root list 4096 Jan  5 09:00 messages/
drwxrwsr-x  3 list list 4096 Jan  5 09:01 qfiles/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   24 Aug 21 02:16 scripts -> /usr/lib/mailman/scripts/
drwxrwsr-x  2 root list 4096 Aug 21 02:15 spam/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   12 Aug 21 02:16 templates -> /etc/mailman/
-rw-r--r--  1 root list   15 Aug 21 02:16 .version
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ sudo /usr/lib/mailman/bin/check_perms -f
directory must be at least 02775: /var/lib/mailman/logs (fixing)
/var/lib/mailman/cron bad group (has: root, expected list) (fixing)
/var/lib/mailman/logs bad group (has: root, expected list) (fixing)
/var/lib/mailman/icons bad group (has: root, expected list) (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages (fixing)
/var/lib/mailman/mail bad group (has: root, expected list) (fixing)
/var/lib/mailman/locks bad group (has: root, expected list) (fixing)
/var/lib/mailman/Mailman bad group (has: root, expected list) (fixing)
/var/lib/mailman/cgi-bin bad group (has: root, expected list) (fixing)
/var/lib/mailman/templates bad group (has: root, expected list) (fixing)
/var/lib/mailman/bin bad group (has: root, expected list) (fixing)
/var/lib/mailman/scripts bad group (has: root, expected list) (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/sk (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/uk (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/nl (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/ru (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/it (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/ro (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/vi (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/ca (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/et (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/tr (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/el (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/ia (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/da (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/ja (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/pt (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/eu (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/hu (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/fi (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/sv (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/gl (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/hr (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/ar (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/no (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/fa (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/fr (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/zh_TW (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/ko (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/cs (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/de (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/sr (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/sl (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/pl (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/es (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/lt (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/pt_BR (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/he (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/zh_CN (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/ast (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/sk/LC_MESSAGES (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/uk/LC_MESSAGES (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/nl/LC_MESSAGES (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/ru/LC_MESSAGES (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/it/LC_MESSAGES (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/ro/LC_MESSAGES (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/vi/LC_MESSAGES (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/ca/LC_MESSAGES (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/et/LC_MESSAGES (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/tr/LC_MESSAGES (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/el/LC_MESSAGES (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/ia/LC_MESSAGES (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/da/LC_MESSAGES (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/ja/LC_MESSAGES (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/pt/LC_MESSAGES (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/eu/LC_MESSAGES (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/hu/LC_MESSAGES (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/fi/LC_MESSAGES (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/sv/LC_MESSAGES (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/gl/LC_MESSAGES (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/hr/LC_MESSAGES (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/ar/LC_MESSAGES (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/no/LC_MESSAGES (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/fa/LC_MESSAGES (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/fr/LC_MESSAGES (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/ko/LC_MESSAGES (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/cs/LC_MESSAGES (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/de/LC_MESSAGES (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/sr/LC_MESSAGES (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/sl/LC_MESSAGES (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/pl/LC_MESSAGES (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/es/LC_MESSAGES (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/lt/LC_MESSAGES (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/he/LC_MESSAGES (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES (fixing)
directory permissions must be 02775: /var/lib/mailman/messages/ast/LC_MESSAGES (fixing)
/var/lib/mailman/archives/private bad group (has: www-data, expected list) (fixing)
/var/lib/mailman/archives/private/mailman.mbox bad group (has: www-data, expected list) (fixing)
/var/lib/mailman/archives/private/mailman bad group (has: www-data, expected list) (fixing)
/var/lib/mailman/archives/private/mailman/index.html bad group (has: www-data, expected list) (fixing)
Problems found: 92
Re-run as list (or root) with -f flag to fix
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ sudo /usr/lib/mailman/bin/check_perms -f
/var/lib/mailman/cron bad group (has: root, expected list) (fixing)
/var/lib/mailman/logs bad group (has: root, expected list) (fixing)
/var/lib/mailman/icons bad group (has: root, expected list) (fixing)
/var/lib/mailman/mail bad group (has: root, expected list) (fixing)
/var/lib/mailman/locks bad group (has: root, expected list) (fixing)
/var/lib/mailman/Mailman bad group (has: root, expected list) (fixing)
/var/lib/mailman/cgi-bin bad group (has: root, expected list) (fixing)
/var/lib/mailman/templates bad group (has: root, expected list) (fixing)
/var/lib/mailman/bin bad group (has: root, expected list) (fixing)
/var/lib/mailman/scripts bad group (has: root, expected list) (fixing)
Problems found: 10
Re-run as list (or root) with -f flag to fix
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ sudo /usr/lib/mailman/bin/check_perms -f
/var/lib/mailman/cron bad group (has: root, expected list) (fixing)
/var/lib/mailman/logs bad group (has: root, expected list) (fixing)
/var/lib/mailman/icons bad group (has: root, expected list) (fixing)
/var/lib/mailman/mail bad group (has: root, expected list) (fixing)
/var/lib/mailman/locks bad group (has: root, expected list) (fixing)
/var/lib/mailman/Mailman bad group (has: root, expected list) (fixing)
/var/lib/mailman/cgi-bin bad group (has: root, expected list) (fixing)
/var/lib/mailman/templates bad group (has: root, expected list) (fixing)
/var/lib/mailman/bin bad group (has: root, expected list) (fixing)
/var/lib/mailman/scripts bad group (has: root, expected list) (fixing)
Problems found: 10
Re-run as list (or root) with -f flag to fix
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$
```

Is this a bug with the mailman, or am I doing it "wrong" somehow, or is something "wrong" with my system?

For a default install, it seems a red flag that it's necessary to check the install permissions, and even worse that the mailman utility can't fix it.  I need to manually change the permissions to whatever these files link to?  That just **seems** excessive.

I would naively lean towards it being a packaging issue, but maybe I borked it somehow, first, so that now it won't install correctly.

see also:

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/30557/howto-fix-errno-13-permission-denied-in-mailman-mailing-lists

http://www.gnu.org/software/mailman/mailman-install/troubleshooting.html

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1292722

Comment: this might be a bug:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mailman/+bug/1266288   but, probably not.  I filed it as a bug in the event.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mailman/+bug/1266288/comments/2

"""
check_perms is not designed to handle symlinks. It looks at the ownership and mode of the symlink itself and complains and then, if requested, fixes the target. Thus, it never "fixes" the symlink which it can't do anyway.

Other than the complaint from check_perms, this is not a problem as the ownership and mode of the symlink itself is irrelevant in practice.
"""

check_perms (nor anything else for that matter) can't change the ownership and mode of the symlink itself. It does "fix" the ownership and mode of the target if necessary and if requested. There is no operational problem with Mailman in practice.

The only issue is that check_perms reports an issue based on the ownership and mode of the symlink itself as it isn't designed to handle this case because standard GNU Mailman doesn't use symlinks in this way.

I have since added https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mailman/+bug/1266288/comments/3 which says

"""
I have looked at this a bit more deeply, and while all I said in comment 2 is correct, there is another issue. Essentially all the issues reported by check_perms are innocuous and just reflect differences between "the Debian way" and standard GNU Mailman, these "fixes"

/var/lib/mailman/archives/private bad group (has: www-data, expected list) (fixing)
/var/lib/mailman/archives/private/mailman.mbox bad group (has: www-data, expected list) (fixing)
/var/lib/mailman/archives/private/mailman bad group (has: www-data, expected list) (fixing)
/var/lib/mailman/archives/private/mailman/index.html bad group (has: www-data, expected list) (fixing)

will break public archive access. This is because the standard recommended ownership and mode for /var/lib/mailman/archives/private would be

drwxrws--- www-data list

but the Debian way is

drwxrws--- list www-data

While this might work, check_perms will change it to

drwxrws--- list list

which won't allow the web server to access public archives. See the Warning at http://www.list.org/mailman-install/node9.html for more detail.

The bottom line is the standard check_perms should not be run against the Debian/Ubuntu package. Debian should either drop check_perms from the package or fix it to follow the Debian way.
"""

Comment: thanks, it just looked weird.  I don't think it's really a bug, per se, because if you know how mailman works, then you know to disregard the error messages.

Comment: "if you know how mailman works" is such a broad statement as to render the rest irrelevant.  See, for example:

https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000016118